# Struggling to create a relevant XSLT file to transform into Access

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to import xml files into a table in MS Access. These files have multiple headers and I am just not coming to terms with the creation of the stylesheets to be able to transform the data... there are numerous very good posts in this forum, but as I said, I am struggling to come to terms. I am hoping that giving a real-time example that someone will "convert" into XSLT so that the real-time data makes sense to me.

This is the input file

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<INTERFACE_BATCH>


-<MATERIAL_ITEM>

<ERP_NUMBER>E371937</ERP_NUMBER>

<MAT_NUMBER>M000319339</MAT_NUMBER>

<PLANT>1AH</PLANT>

<PROCESS>NORMAL_CREATE</PROCESS>

<DELETE>N</DELETE>

<LONG_DES>KIT; TYPE PISTON, APPLICATION ENGINE, COMPRISING PINS; OEM P/N: 1202400Z26ND OEM BB MOTORS, MODEL/MACHINE NO: NISSAN UD460</LONG_DES>

<SHORT_DES>KIT;PISTON,ENGINE,PINS,1202400Z26ND</SHORT_DES>

<MAT_GROUP>EAA14</MAT_GROUP>

<MAT_TYPE>ERSA</MAT_TYPE>

<UOM>EA</UOM>

<STORAGE_LOCATION>0011</STORAGE_LOCATION>

<VALUATION_CLASS>3040</VALUATION_CLASS>

<LANGUAGE>EN</LANGUAGE>

<REQUESTOR_NAME>TMAKGETA</REQUESTOR_NAME>

<REQUESTOR_EMAIL>TMAKGETA@CCBAGROUP.COM</REQUESTOR_EMAIL>

<LAST_UPDATE_BY>WBEZUIDENHOUT</LAST_UPDATE_BY>


-<DESCRIPTOR>

<DESCRIPTOR_NAME>KIT</DESCRIPTOR_NAME>


-<DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTIES>


-<DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY>

<DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY_NAME>APPLICATION</DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY_NAME>

<DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY_VALUE>ENGINE</DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY_VALUE>

<DESCRIPTOR_PROP_UOM>NOT APPLICABLE</DESCRIPTOR_PROP_UOM>

</DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY>


-<DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY>

<DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY_NAME>COMPRISING</DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY_NAME>

<DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY_VALUE>PINS</DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY_VALUE>

<DESCRIPTOR_PROP_UOM>NOT APPLICABLE</DESCRIPTOR_PROP_UOM>

</DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY>


-<DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY>

<DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY_NAME>TYPE</DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY_NAME>

<DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY_VALUE>PISTON</DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY_VALUE>

<DESCRIPTOR_PROP_UOM>NOT APPLICABLE</DESCRIPTOR_PROP_UOM>

</DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY>

</DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTIES>

</DESCRIPTOR>


-<PART_DETAIL>

<PART_NO>1202400Z26ND</PART_NO>

<MANUF>2003476</MANUF>

<PART_TYPE>OEM</PART_TYPE>

</PART_DETAIL>

</MATERIAL_ITEM>

</INTERFACE_BATCH>
```

Comment: Presumably the XML you have shown is the input of your transformation. What should the output be?

Comment: I think the XML is broken. You can not put text (the hyphen) in front of the root node.

Comment: This is the template file I am trying to create:

Comment: Don't copy XML from the preview in Internet Explorer. Use the *actual* XML source: Open the file in a text editor, copy from there. Trim it down to the necessary minimum.

Comment: Hi Michael... I have copied my attempt of the template file so that you can see my errors.

Comment: Apologies Tomalak, but no matter I open with (other IE), I get a 2 line string which pastes the same :(

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it right! :)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <dataroot>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </dataroot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="INTERFACE_BATCH">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PART_DETAIL">
    <PART_DETAIL>
        <ERP_NUMBER><xsl:value-of select="../ERP_NUMBER"/></ERP_NUMBER>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </PART_DETAIL>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Now that we finally know what is your expected output, note that you can make your 1st template `<xsl:template match="/INTERFACE_BATCH">` and eliminate the 3rd one. And shorten `<ERP_NUMBER><xsl:value-of select="../ERP_NUMBER"/></ERP_NUMBER>` to `<xsl:copy-of select="../ERP_NUMBER"/>`.

Comment: Thanks Michael.hor257k. I made the changes as suggested. Is this to improve the process or for correct syntax etc?

Comment: Less code = easier to read + better performance. The latter will not be noticeable in your case, but over time will reduce your electricity bill and global warming.